# GetVersionEx deprecation - how to get product type (VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER) from newer API's

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to check if the OS is a domain controller (`VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER`). It was easy to do so using `GetVersionEx` function using [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx). But the MSDN page for `GetVersionEx` suggests that this function is deprecated and also we see a warning in visual studio 2015.

Are there any newer API's which can provide this information? I know there are newer [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972.aspx) that tell what kind of OS it is but I did not see anything for getting the product type.

Comment: You can [use this](http://www.naughter.com/dtwinver.html).  Does a much more comprehensive job than `GetVersionEx`

Comment: Read the docs you linked to. VerifyVersionInfo with VER_PRODUCT_TYPE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem with using VerifyVersionInfo is that the MSDN page says : [VerifyVersionInfo may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 10. Instead, use the Version Helper functions]

Comment: The helpers are built on top of VerifyVersionInfo. Realistically though MS are just starting that the entire landscape may be different in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I looked how NodeJS / [libuv solved the OS version number](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/3908af563c9a6dd64238a8867f5a2864dd146a09/src/win/util.c#L1622) in order to figure out how to do it myself. They use `RtlGetVersion()` if it is available, otherwise they fall back to `GetVersionEx()`.

**The solution I came up with was:**

```
// Windows10SCheck.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

// Function to get the OS version number
//
// Uses RtlGetVersion() is available, otherwise falls back to GetVersionEx()
bool getosversion(OSVERSIONINFOEX* osversion) {
    NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEX);
    *(FARPROC*)&RtlGetVersion = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "RtlGetVersion");

    if (RtlGetVersion != NULL)
    {
        // RtlGetVersion uses 0 (STATUS_SUCCESS)
        // as return value when succeeding
        return RtlGetVersion(osversion) == 0;
    }
    else {
        // GetVersionEx was deprecated in Windows 10
        // Only use it as fallback
        #pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        return GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO)osversion);
    }
}

int main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osinfo;
    osinfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osinfo);
    osinfo.szCSDVersion[0] = L'\0';

    if (!getosversion(&osinfo)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get OS version\n";
    }

    std::cout << osinfo.dwMajorVersion << "." << osinfo.dwMinorVersion << "." << osinfo.dwBuildNumber << "\n";

    DWORD dwReturnedProductType = 0;

    if (!GetProductInfo(osinfo.dwMajorVersion, osinfo.dwMinorVersion, 0, 0, &dwReturnedProductType)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get product info\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Product type: " << std::hex << dwReturnedProductType;

}
```

**Output on my machine:**

```
10.0.15063
Product type: 1b
```

What the product type means can be found at: [GetProductInfo function | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo)